# Automatic indentation in julia code using emacs

Tags: emacs, julia

Recently I had to do a fresh installation of the os, including julia and emacs. The steps I did are straghforwardly known:

```
1. Alt + x list-packages .
2. Find the package you want, move cursor to the line, press Enter . ...
3. Put cursor on the pane, press Tab to move cursor to the “Install” button then press  Enter .
4. The package is now installed.
```

It has been a while since I did this, but as far as I remember the package is `julia-mode`. This package had all the editing julia-code stuff, including automatic indentation.

Now, upon a fresh installation, it doesn't have the identation feature installed. I've tried to install packages like `aggressive-indent`or `gnu-indent`, but indentation is still missing.

Comment: C-h m describes modes active in the buffer. 

Is julia-mode enabled?

Is electric-indent-mode enabled?  If electric-indent-mode is enabled, then emacs will adjust indent when typing the enter key, or when typing the tab key anywhere on a line.  If electric-indent-mode is not enabled, then emacs will adjust indent only when typing the tab key before the first non-whitespace on a line.

Comment: Uhmm I'm not sure how to do this. I can see that in `Enabled minor modes` electric-indent is in the list. Below the heading `(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)`I can see that the julia-mode.el is listed.

Comment: Hmm.  Does this problem occur in all parts of the file?  File content might prevent indentation in some places, if an earlier part of the file has unbalanced quotes "..." or comment delimiters #= ... =#, so emacs treats the line as if it is inside a string literal or a comment.

Comment: (Gnu Emacs version 28.2.  M-x list-packages shows: julia-mode 20230712.1524 installed, julia-repl 20230529.943 installed, use-package 20230426.2324 installed, bind-key 20230203.2004 dependency, s 20220902.1511 dependency)

Comment: Uhmm, strange. To add the julia-repl mode I add the lines sugested [here](https://github.com/tpapp/julia-repl) in my emacs file, but opening now a new session of emacs the error message says `File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, julia-repl`

Comment: If you were previously able to use package-install to install julia-mode and julia-repl separately, you should be able to add the following to your .emacs file:
`(require 'julia-mode)`
`(require 'julia-repl)`
`(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'julia-repl-mode) ;; always use minor mode`